# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, async-await, next.js, react-context

I want add {searchWord} from useContext, to function with API call `getServerSideProps()`, but I got different errors.
The last one: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext').

Maybe something wrong with my provider???

File with API call function `/search-results`:

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import { Text, Stack, Box, SimpleGrid, IconButton, Button, useQuery } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import ListOfCards from '../components/ListOfCards';
import { SearchContext, SearchContextProps } from './_app';
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { ChevronLeftIcon } from '@chakra-ui/icons';

function SearchResult({ searchResultForMapping }) {
  console.log(searchResultForMapping)
  const [queryKey, setQueryKey] = useState('lebowski');
  const { searchWord } = useContext<SearchContextProps>(SearchContext);


    useEffect(() => {
      setQueryKey(searchWord);
    }, [searchWord]);

    const mockup = {"status":"OK","copyright":"Copyright (c) 2022 The New York Times Company. All Rights Reserved.","has_more":false,"num_results":1,"results":[{"display_title":"The Big Lebowski","mpaa_rating":"R","critics_pick":1,"byline":"Janet Maslin","headline":"Big Lebowski, the (Movie)","summary_short":"In a film both sweeter and loopier than \u0026quot;Fargo,\u0026quot; Joel and Ethan Coen and their rogues' gallery of actors explore Southern California's post-hippie, surfer-dude bowling scene. The results are irresistible, at least for audiences on the film's laid-back wavelength and in tune with its deadpan humor. With shaggy, baggy looks that belie his performance's fine comic control, Jeff Bridges plays a guy who truly deserves to be called Dude, and is by turns oblivious and indignant once a ruined rug leads him into neo-noir escapades. In a film that certainly keeps its audience guessing what might happen next (Saddam Hussein renting bowling shoes?), John Turturro takes the cake as the most fiendish of bowlers. — Janet Maslin","publication_date":"1998-03-06","opening_date":"1998-03-06","date_updated":"2017-11-02 04:17:54","link":{"type":"article","url":"https://www.nytimes.com/1998/03/06/movies/film-review-a-bowling-ball-s-eye-view-of-reality.html","suggested_link_text":"Read the New York Times Review of The Big Lebowski"},"multimedia":null}]}
    
      return (
        <><Button leftIcon={<ChevronLeftIcon />} colorScheme='pink' variant='solid' position='absolute' right='20px;' top='25px'>
        <Link href="/">Home</Link>
      </Button>
        <Box p={5}>
          <SimpleGrid gap={12} p={12} columns={1}>
            <Text fontSize='4xl'> Search Result for keyword "{queryKey} i {searchWord}"</Text>
            <Stack spacing={3} rowGap={3}>
              <ListOfCards movieDetails={mockup} />
            </Stack>
            <Text fontSize='xl'><Link href="/">Search last key word..</Link> </Text>
          </SimpleGrid>
        </Box></>
      );
  }
  

const { searchWord } = useContext<SearchContextProps>(SearchContext);

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  // const queryWord = 'iron'
  const queryWord = searchWord;
  const apiKey = "nTCRt5WnuaiL5Q5VsPEgeGM8oZifd3Ma";
  const endpoint = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/movies/v2/reviews/search.json?";
  const createUrl = `${endpoint}query=${queryWord}&api-key=${apiKey}`;
  const res = fetch(createUrl);
  const searchResultForMapping = (await res).json();

return { props: { searchResultForMapping } };}


export default SearchResult
```

Page where i setSearchWord `SearchLine.tsx`:

```
import { Button } from "@chakra-ui/button";
import { Input, InputGroup, InputRightElement } from "@chakra-ui/input";
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { SearchContext } from "../pages/_app";


const SearchLine = () : JSX.Element =>  {
  const { searchWord, setSearchWord, searchHistory, setSearchHistory } = useContext(SearchContext);

  const router = useRouter()

  const handleChange = (keyword) => setSearchWord(keyword.target.value);
  
  const handleOnclick = () => {
    setSearchHistory([...searchHistory, searchWord]);
    router.push('/search-result');
}
  
    return (
      <InputGroup size="md">
      <Input
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder='Enter the name of the movie or keyword'
        size='md'
      />
        <InputRightElement width="4.5rem">
          <Button onClick={handleOnclick}>
            Enter
          </Button>
        </InputRightElement>
      </InputGroup>
    )
  }

  export default SearchLine;
```

my `_app.tsx`:

```
import { ChakraProvider } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import { QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import { createContext, useContext, useMemo, useState } from 'react';
export interface SearchContextProps {
  searchWord: string;
  setSearchWord: (f: string) => void;
  searchHistory: string[]; 
  setSearchHistory: (f: string[]) => void;
}

export const SearchContext = createContext<SearchContextProps>({
  searchWord: '',
  setSearchWord: () => {
    // do nothing
  },
  searchHistory: [],
  setSearchHistory: () => {
    // do nothing
  },
});

const SearchProvider = (props: any) => {
  const [searchWord, setSearchWord] = useState('');
  const [searchHistory, setSearchHistory] = useState('');
  const value = useMemo(() => ({ searchWord, setSearchWord, searchHistory, setSearchHistory }), [searchWord]);

  return <SearchContext.Provider value={value} {...props} />;
};
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps): JSX.Element {
  const context = useContext(SearchContext);
  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
        <SearchProvider>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </SearchProvider>
    </ChakraProvider>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `SearchProvider` is wrong.

```
const SearchProvider = (props: any) => {
  const [searchWord, setSearchWord] = useState('');
  const [searchHistory, setSearchHistory] = useState('');
  const value = useMemo(() => ({ searchWord, setSearchWord, searchHistory, setSearchHistory }), [searchWord]);

  return (
    <SearchContext.Provider value={value}>
      {props.children}
    </SearchContext.Provider>
  );
  
};
```